# Installing Oracle Developer Studio on Ubuntu, but Java installation was not found on this computer

Tags: software-installation, java, environment-variables, jdk, oracle

I am on Ubuntu 22.03.1. I want to use Oracle Developer Studio as Fortran IDE.

I downloaded
OracleDeveloperStudio12.6-linux-x86-rpm.tar.bz2 from [here](https://www.oracle.com/application-development/developerstudio/), unzipped it, and trying to execute it's installation shell script

```
sudo ./developerstudio.sh
```

Terminal returns:

```
Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Java installation was not found on this computer
Java 1.5.0_03 or later is required for installing Oracle Developer Studio. Make sure that Java is properly installed and run installer again.
You can specify valid Java location using --javahome installer argument.

To download Java installation bundle (JDK or JRE), visit http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
```

So I proceeded to install JDK. I downloaded `jdk-18_linux-x64_bin.deb` from the link. Trying to install and configure with terminal and run the `sudo ./developerstudio.sh`  command again, it gives me the same error. Then I uninstalled JDK and reinstalled again with GUI, still the same error. Then I used `apt-get` to install jdk package, still the same error.

I believe my java is installed:

```
$ java --version

openjdk 11.0.16 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing)


$ whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz

$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Aug 19 15:21 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java

$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Aug 19 15:21 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

I also exported its path in ~/.bashrc, but it still has the same problem.

```
export PATH="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: 2 issues: JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME you have not set? and you did not do this: "You can specify valid Java location using --javahome installer argument." ? either should work.

Comment: @Rinzwind I edited my .bashrc, included: `export JAVA_HOME="usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"` and `export PATH=$PATH:JAVA_HOME/bin`, restarted the terminal and it still reports the same problem. I checked the environment variables and they read by my terminal. I am not sure how to use `--javahome installer argument` on Linux, could you give me some guidance? Thank you!

Comment: Well I see that the package that you have is rpm. So maybe it search Java on different place. Normally it should use JAVA_HOME but who knows... By the way you are working with very old software (The required Java 1.5.0_03 is before Java SE 6 ->December 2006).  Anyway you can try specify valid Java location using --javahome installer argument. So this mean to use: `sudo ./developerstudio.sh --javahome /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin`

Comment: I honestly don't know what will happen. Most probably you will need to return to java 6/7/8 to make it work.In this case you need manually to install old JDK. Just for your info while Java generally is backward compatible there is small amount of incompatible code in JVM which if you need in your program will not work. Any IDE is heavy program so the possibility to use this small about of incompatible code is actually big.

Comment: Unnecessary code in Java first is deprecated and after 2, 3 version removed. But when you have more then 5 versions of Java you can expect that you can have problems with compatibility.